# jquery show div below svg circle

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, svg

I have an SVG with a line of circles and each time you click on a circle i want a pop up to appear directly below the circle with an arrow like tool tip,

The problem I'm having is that the tooltip positioning is dependent on the where the mouse was clicked and not relative to the circle (i want it to appear in the middle of the circle).

I am using jquery ui position utility to do this currently.

Here is the code

```
thisSeat.click(function(e){ 
    $('#' + seatID).position({
        my: "top",
        at: "center bottom",
        of: e,
        offset: "-8 12",
       collision: "none"
   });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We really need to see more than this, something we can run as a stack snippet or jsfiddle would be best.

Comment: hi here you go http://jsfiddle.net/1wp1zLf7/1/

Comment: You could get offset position of circle and move popover to center of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use JQuery UI :) You could use offset for clicked circle. Try this one:

```
$("circle").each(function () {
    var seatID = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        $(".ticket-price").not('#' + seatID).hide();
        $("#" + seatID).show();

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var popoverWidth = $('#' + seatID).width()

        $('#' + seatID).css(
            {position: 'absolute', 
             top: (offset.top + 20)+'px', 
             left: offset.left - (popoverWidth/2) - 5 + 'px'
            });
    });
});
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wp1zLf7/2/. Notice positioning absolutely and small adjustments to element position to display in the center of the circle.

Comment: Thanks for this worked well i had to minus the parent offset to get it to position correctly but after that looked great!